# Generate random height and apply to each div on the page

Tags: javascript, css

Don't know why I'm struggling with this so much, but essentially I have a bunch of divs on a page. I want to generate a different random height for each of them, and then loop through each of them and apply it.

Trying to use a Do While for this (first time I've used one). This works but does it seem like the best/easiest way?

THANK YOU!

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('section div.images')
let randomNum

const generateRandomHeight = (maxNum) => {
  randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum)
  return randomNum
}

images.forEach(image => {
  do {
    generateRandomHeight(400)
  }
  while (randomNum < 300)
  image.style.height = randomNum + "px"
})
```

Comment: you don't need a do/while, instead, make a random number between 0 and 300

Comment: Why are you using a `do while` like that? That just means that your maximum is actually 300 instead of the 400 you provided to the function.

Comment: If you need a randomNumber between 300 and 400, you could do `const rand = 300 + generateRandomHeight(100)`

Comment: Aha thanks Daniel! So obvious now. I knew I was overcomplicating it